# Copy one account client-side rule to all client-side rules

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there any way to copy the outlook rule of one account to another account using VBA code. I have researched on the internet I have not found anything related to my question, Pls help me. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are different languages. Please read the tag descriptions and use only appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that. However, you can use a low-level functionality to access rules. Use the `PropertyAccessor` object to get and set item-level properties that are not explicitly exposed in the Outlook object model, or properties for the following non-item objects: `AddressEntry`, `AddressList`, `Attachment`, `ExchangeDistributionList`, `ExchangeUser`, `Folder`, `Recipient`, and `Store`.

Rules are kept as hidden items in your Inbox folder (see the associated content which is not visible in the Outlook UI). You may use `MFCMAPI` or `OutlookSpy` for exploring the hidden content.